# can't Archive my project Xcode 11 and 11.1 also on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, ipad

[image]

Am using Xcode 11 to fixed iOS 13 and above issues and crashes after that i can't archive my files. Am stuck on after some files in my own project. Anyone help me, please. Thanks

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: am not getting any error.

Comment: so you can just wait for some time...may be some process is ongoing in background by mac os.

Comment: am waiting nearby 4 to 5 hrs but no response.